# Flatten works in output but not in Global Workspace?

Tags: front-end, core-language

I am trying Michael Trott's Sierpinski Triangle.

```
Clear[SierpinskiTriangle]
SierpinskiTriangle[1] = {Polygon[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3.]}}]};
SierpinskiTriangle[n_Integer] := 
 N[Flatten[
   SierpinskiTriangle[n] = 
    SierpinskiTriangle[n - 1] /. {Polygon[{a_, b_, c_}] ->
       {
        Polygon[{a, (a + b)/2, (a + c)/2}],
        Polygon[{(a + b)/2, b, (b + c)/2}],
        Polygon[{(a + c)/2, (b + c)/2, c}]
        }}]]
```

I have a question about the flattening. If I do:

```
SierpinskiTriangle[2]
```

The output is:

{Polygon[{{-1., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {-0.5, 0.866025}}], 
 Polygon[{{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {0.5, 0.866025}}], 
 Polygon[{{-0.5, 0.866025}, {0.5, 0.866025}, {0., 1.73205}}]}

It looks flattened. But if I do:

```
?SierpinskiTriangle
```

The output for Sierpinski[2] looks like this:

SierpinskiTriangle[2]={{Polygon[{{-1,0},{0,0},{-(1/2),0.866025}}],Polygon[{{0,0},{1,0},{1/2,0.866025}}],Polygon[{{-(1/2),0.866025},{1/2,0.866025},{0,1.73205}}]}}

See, it doesn't look flattened. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: I think this is true in general for memoization: It seems `Definition` returns the `=` part  in`f[n_] := blah[f[n] =...]` . Using a simpler example `ClearAll[f1, f2];
f1[x_] := N[Flatten[f1[x] = {f1[x - 1] + f1[x - 2]}]];
f1[0] = f1[1] = 1;
f1[3]` and  `f2[x_] := f2[x] = N[Flatten[{f2[x - 1] + f2[x - 2]}]];
f2[0] = f2[1] = 1;
f2[3]`  compare `?f1` and `?f2`.